# normalize json but keep id from top level -

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json file from an API response that broadly follows the following schema

```
import pandas as pd 


j =[
  {
    "orders": [
      {
        "orderId": 0,
        "items": [
          { "item_1": "x", "item_price": 5.99 },
          { "item_1": "y", "item_price": 15.99 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

What I'm trying to do is to normalize the json but retain the orderId from the top level so I can re-join the datasets further down a data pipeline.

I thought this could be done with one of the keyword arguments in `pd.json_normalize`

```
df_orders = pd.json_normalize(j,record_path=['orders'])

print(df_orders)

   orderId                                              items
0        0  [{'item_1': 'x', 'item_price': 5.99}, {'item_1...
```

---

```
df_items = pd.json_normalize(j,record_path=['orders','items'])
print(df_items)

  item_1  item_price
0      x        5.99
1      y       15.99
```

---

What I would like is

```
  item_1  item_price  orders.orderId
0      x        5.99  0
1      y       15.99  0
```

--

I've gone through the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

and attempted to use

```
pd.json_normalize(j,record_path=['orders','items'], meta=['orders'])
```

which just appends the entire json object to each record.

```
  item_1  item_price                                             orders
0      x        5.99  {'orderId': 0, 'items': [{'item_1': 'x', 'item...
1      y       15.99  {'orderId': 0, 'items': [{'item_1': 'x', 'item...
```

any tips using `pd.json_normalize`?

I have no issue in parsing the json out manually and doing this in a 2 step process but want to avoid further depencies in my pipeline to keep things dynamic if i can help it.

Comment: if you do not want any dependencies, you can try this : ``pd.json_normalize(j,record_path=['orders','items'], meta=['orders']).assign(orderId = lambda df: df.orders.str.get('orderId')).drop(columns='orders')``. if you are not averse to jmespath, it could be helpful here

Comment: not sure what you mean by aligned. the code shared above should work, since Pandas aligns on the index before any operation is computed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try putting an extra pair of square brackets on the `meta` parameter and specify upto `orderId`.

```
pd.json_normalize(j,record_path=['orders','items'], meta=[['orders', 'orderId']])
```

**Result:**

```
  item_1  item_price orders.orderId
0      x        5.99              0
1      y       15.99              0
```

The syntax of `meta` in [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) is that whenever you want to access a second level field down from top level, you have to specify it under a *second level* list.  The list in the second level in this case, i.e. `['orders', 'orderId']` acts like a path.  We still can't skip specifying the top level list even when we have 2 items in this second level list. For reference, we can look at the examples in the [official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and look at e.g. the case we want to access the field `governor` in the example.

The field `orderId` is regarded as a second level field instead of top level, probably owing to the fact that the field `orders` is regarded as the top level, which in turn is because it is the data `j` that we pass to [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) as input data and [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) counts levels based on this input data `j`. Even though we specify `record_path`, these relative levels are still the same.

Comment: beautiful worked perfectly. why the need for a list of lists?

Comment: @Umar.H  Looking at the example of [official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), you can see we need to enclose in list of list to get the field `governor` in the example.

Comment: do'h can't believe I missed that! thanks again!

Comment: @Umar.H  Yup, I also can't believe this.  You solved a lot of similar problems for others. Probably we are at sometimes too concentrate on a problem and got confused.  :-)

Comment: @Umar.H  I came up with some more writing about why the need for a list of lists.  Trust that you already know why now but you can still take a look and advise me if you find any fine-tuning of the writing required.  :-)

Comment: your adjustments are fantastic mate, you should do a PR do the docs and improve it :)

Answer (score 0):

`meta` expects a nested list of lists (strings denoting the path to the field) for each additional field you would like included in your flattened DataFrame.

This works:

```py
pd.json_normalize(j,record_path=['orders','items'],meta[['orders','orderId']])
```

```sh
  item_1  item_price orders.orderId
0      x        5.99              0
1      y       15.99              0
```

Comment: this is the same as answer above?

Comment: Yes! Nothing additional here. I guess I didn't refresh the page before posting my answer, or at least didn't see the other answer. Glad you got sorted!